# Make database transactions block code execution during tests

Tags: django, postgresql, selenium, transactions

I have a django backend angularJS frontEnd app with a postgresql database. I am running e2e tests using StaticLiveServerTestCase, which extends LiveServerTestCase and subclasses TransactionTestCase. TransactionTestCase does not wrap each test in a transaction (so you can explicitly commit / rollback).

My test setup is as follows:

1. Load fixture data
2. Manipulate data further in the my testClass setUp() method, to generate specific edge cases (this can involve creating, updating, or destroying objects in the database).
3. Log in to my application using selenium webDriver and verify the presence / non-presence of certain elements corresponding with the userScenario under test.

The issue I'm running in to is that **the manipulation I'm doing in my setUp method sometimes does not seem to be committing before my webdriver makes the GET to my application URL** (which hits a django view that queries the tables I am manipulating in setUp)...the data returned by my view is the old, un-manipulated state of the database from fixture-load. If I refresh the page using the webDriver after making the get, the correct data will often show up, but not always...it does not seem to be deterministic.

I am guessing this has to do with some sort of race condition between the setUp method fully completing its transaction to the test database, and the reads generated by my application test-server connection. They are two separate connections, and to my knowledge the transactions in each of these connections are not guaranteed to happen in any particular order.

The isolation level of my database is `psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE`

**My question:** Is there any way to guarantee / force a database transaction to occur, before other transactions execute? I have tried using django.db.transaction.commit() but that does not seem to do the trick...

Comment: Another note: This only happens during parallel test execution. Not sure if that has any impact. I'm using pytest-django and pytest-xdist for parallelization.

Comment: I'm also noticing that the first test to run on database gw1 consistently fails, regardless of the test.